# Django не видит css файлы static

Tags: python, html, django, pycharm, static

Столкнулся с проблемой: *джанго не видит static файлы. В частности, css.*

> Вот структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> settings.py (DEBUG = True):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = []

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

> aboutus.html (На данный момент пытаюсь подключить к нему внешний
> aboutus.css):

```
{% extends 'mainapp/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" href="{% static 'mainapp/css/aboutus.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" /> # здесь aboutus.css pycharm подчеркивает, ибо не видит
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block title %}
        О нас
        {% endblock %}
        {% block content %}

        <div id='div1'>
            <span id='span1'>▼</span> Кто мы такие?</div>
        <div id='div2'>
            1 <span class='span2'>2</span>3
            <span  class='span2'>4 </span><br>
            5 <br>
            6 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWycy6WRv7w">7</a>
        </div>

        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

> aboutus.css :

```
#div1 {
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-bottom : 20px
}
#span1 {
    font-size: 9pt
}
#div2 {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    line-height: 2.5;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom : 20px;
    border: 1px solid gray
}
.span2 {
    color: red
}
```

> urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

> UPD:

'django.contrib.staticfiles' в INSTALLED_APPS есть

***Я переделал структуру проекта по вашим советам. Теперь она выглядит так:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> SETTINGS.PY теперь выглядит так:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mainapp/static'),]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

***Aboutus.html***

```
{% extends 'mainapp/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<html>
    <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/aboutus.css' %} /" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block title %}
        О нас
        {% endblock %}
        {% block content %}

        <div id='div1'>
            <span id='span1'>▼</span> Кто мы такие?</div>
        <div id='div2'>
            1 <span class='span2'>2 </span>3
            <span  class='span2'>4 </span><br>
            4 <br>
            5 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWycy6WRv7w">6</a>
        </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

***STATICFILES_FINDERS***

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

]
```

***Но все еще ничего не помогает(***

Comment: `./manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: Я работаю с отладочным сервером, а collectstatic нужен вроде для уже настоящего?

Comment: Прописал collectstatic. Все прошло успешно, но никаких изменений. Файл css все еще не видит

Comment: Это не может быть из-за того, что у меня mac os?

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_ROOT]`

Comment: Это не помогло. Выдало ошибку ?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

Comment: Покажите STATICFILES_FINDERS

Comment: STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `static` не нужно дублировать папку приложения внутри, просто `static/css`, уберите вложенную папку `mainapp` внутри `static`.

Далее, в `STATICFILES_DIRS` укажите путь:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mainapp/static'),]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

Comment: Сделал все как вы говорите, но результата не дало

Comment: Ура! Я пересоздал новый проект и попробовал в нем. Все получилось) Видимо я просто что-то сломал в прежнем проекте джанго